# Pass two viewmodels to action

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I work around e-commerce`s cart. I have two view models.

First for customers info:

```
public class CartViewModel
    {
      public string FirstName{get;set;}
      public string Email{get;set;}
      //... other fields
}
```

And second for customers cart:

```
 public class ProductsCart
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int ItemsOrdered { get; set; }
     }
```

The main thing is that cart storing in users localStorage and I should pass it from localStorage with customers info via jquery to MVC`s action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConfirmOrder(CartViewModel model, IEnumerable<ProductsCart> cart)
    {
        // validate and save to database 
    }
```

And I have javascript method to send data to my action:

```
function ConfirmOrder() {
    var serverCart = LocalCartToSercerCart(); //see first screnshot 
    var customerData = $("#FORM_WITH_CUSTOMERS_VIEW_MODEL").serialize();   

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/Cart/ConfirmOrder",
        data: {model: customerData, cart: serverCart  }
    })
    .done(function () {
      //do something
    });

}
```

But I always getting null value for my **CartViewModel** (screenshot 2)

I also attached files with my debug info.

If I write javascript function like this:

```
function ConfirmOrder() {    
  var customerData = $("#cartForm").serialize();

$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "/Cart/ConfirmOrder",
   data: customerData
  })
 .done(function () {   
   //some code
    });    
}
```

I getting only model data (see screenshot 3)

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**
I wrote code using Igor`s answer, but still getting null in action parameter
[image]

Answer (score 7):

The reason you are receiving a null value is because the data is not being converted to JSON before it is sent to the server. The JQUERY ajax call does not do this automatically for you. You can easily convert it using `JSON.stringify` like so.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/Cart/ConfirmOrder",
    data: JSON.stringify({model: customerData, cart: serverCart }),
    contentType: 'json' // added to tell the server the format of the data being sent
})
.done(function () {
  //do something
});
```

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) converts your object to properly formatted JSON which is then sent to the server. From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

**Note**
This edit was based on @StephenMuecke comment below. My previous answer was not correct, the only change that was necessary was to your javascript ajax call, not your c# code.

Comment: or he could use [tuples](https://nitinasp.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/tuples-in-mvc/)

Comment: I tried your like you wrote but still null (here screen of my job) https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-dajRUS_6ynQUFLakQ3RTJ5NFU

Comment: @dantey89 - not sure what you are sending but I generally do not follow external links (safe browsing and all). If you have additional questions or an update please update your question with those details, I will be more than happy to respond that way. If its just a question you can also post that in a comment (same place you just posted this link).

Comment: Sory, did like you say

Comment: Its not by design at all. You could have a hundred different models and parameters if your want. As for the edit, if you stringify it, then you also need the `contentType: 'json'` option as well

Comment: @StephenMuecke - So this is not a restriction with MVC as it is with Web API (only one FromBody allowed in a method)?

Comment: No, not at all (although its cleaner to have a single view model, you can actually have as many as you want)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - thanks for the correction. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Manoz, You cannot use `tuple` - a `tuple` does not have a parameterless constructor so the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot initialize it.

Comment: Thanks guys for your attantion and help, but it still don't work - not with ConfirmOrderViewModel  , neither with stringify and contenttype 'json'

Comment: @dantey89, The code Igor has show will work correctly with your original method (i.e. `public ActionResult ConfirmOrder(CartViewModel model, IEnumerable<ProductsCart> cart)` (and both stringify and contentType are required because `servercart` is an array of objects

Comment: @dantey89 - the only other thing I can think of is that `customerData` is empty in your javascript code. You have a screenshot showing the array `serverCart` but not showing the content of `customerData` (later assigned to `model`.

Comment: no, it's not empt, you can see it on 3d screenshot. I think it is problem in different data format in 'model' and 'cart'. Javscript's typeof() shows that 'Model' is string and 'cart' is object. I think it needed to been in same format before sending...

Comment: @dantey89, Try `.serializeArray()` rather that `.serialize()`

Answer (score 1):

After many tries I finaly found solution. For me it was this javascript code:

```
function ConfirmOrder() {

    var serverCart = LocalCartToSercerCart();   
    var customerData = $('#cartForm').serialize();

    var paramObj = {};
    $.each($('#cartForm').serializeArray(), function (_, kv) {
        paramObj[kv.name] = kv.value;
    });

    var Data = {
        model: paramObj,
        cart: serverCart
    }


    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/Cart/ConfirmOrder",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(Data)

    })
    .done(function () {

    });

}
```

And this action in MVC :

```
 [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult ConfirmOrder(CartViewModel model, IEnumerable<ProductsCart> cart)
    {
    // operations with data
    }
```

The kye was right transformation form data to javacript object. As I understand,  Serialize() method convert form to WebForm data and it is not valid to be send as a ONE OF THE PARAMETERS. Serialize() must be whole object... Maybe I'm wrong, you can write your suggetions in comments, I'll be glad to read it.

Special thanks to **Igor** and **StephenMuecke**